# Using glade# with gtk# 3

Tags: gtk, gtk#, glade

I've downloaded and installed GTK# 3 as NuGet package. But I haven't found a glade NuGet package. How can I get a glade# Version that works with GTK3? How to set up the Project in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything like Glade# 3 ready for Gtk#. Is Gtk# 3 completely finished? I don't think so either, since in the mono pages you still can only find downloads for Gtk# 2.x

My advice, anyway, is not to rely on designers. They create code that tie you to a given development environment, code which you don't know, an that many times is way more complex than it should be.

Creating widgets is easy. In order to create layouts, use **Gtk.VBox** and **Gtk.HBox**. For actions in your windows, instead of repeating widgets use **Gtk.Action** (it seems this is deprecated and you should be using GAction instead). You can create a menu item from an action using `Gtk.Action.CreateMenuItem()` and a toolbar item by means of `Gtk.Action.CreateToolbarItem()`.

It is easy and rewarding: try this [Gtk# tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/) if you don't believe me.

Hope this helps.